# Django Forms Clean_Data key error

Tags: python, django, forms

at the moment I am encountering a strange issue, that I cannot seem to solve.

I have a form that is used for registering a user. I have a custom user model in my Django 1.7.4 project. Everything works, but lately, the site crashes if a user with the same e-mail address already exists.

Here is the trace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://mysite.dbz.dev/purchase/step1/Business

Django Version: 1.7.4
Python Version: 2.7.9
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_summernote',
 'usercp',
 'clickatell',
 'downloadcenter',
 'purchaseorder',
 'paypalrestsdk',
 'import_export',
 'debug_toolbar')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'mysite.middleware.AutoLogout',
 'mysite.middleware.LocationChecker')


Traceback:
File "/home/bs/envs/main-page/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/var/www/vhosts/main-page/purchaseorder/views.py" in step1
  194.         if form.is_valid():
File "/home/bs/envs/main-page/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  162.         return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
File "/home/bs/envs/main-page/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  154.             self.full_clean()
File "/home/bs/envs/main-page/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  353.         self._clean_fields()
File "/home/bs/envs/main-page/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_fields
  371.                     value = getattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name)()
File "/var/www/vhosts/main-page/usercp/forms.py" in clean_email2
  343.         email = self.cleaned_data["email"]

Exception Type: KeyError at /purchase/step1/Business
Exception Value: 'email'
```

And these are my cleaning methods:

```
   def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        try:
            Customer.objects.get(email=email)
        except Customer.DoesNotExist:
            return email

        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['duplicate_email'],
            code='duplicate_email',
        )

    def clean_email2(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"] #<!--- THIS IS THE LINE WHERE IT FAILES / ERRORS
        email2 = self.cleaned_data["email2"]

        if email != email2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['no_mail_match'],
                code='no_mail_match'
            )
        return email2
```

Does anyone understand why it would fail, when there is an existing user ? It seems to me that the cleaned_data gets replaced with an object. But this does not make sense to me.

Comment: You should be doing this in the `clean` field: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In forms, if you want to clean depending on multiple fields, you have to do a `clean` method instead of a `clean_field` method :

```
def clean(self): # change this line
    email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
    email2 = self.cleaned_data.get("email2")

    if email != email2:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['no_mail_match'],
            code='no_mail_match'
        )
    return email2
```

**--EDIT--**

Edited with [Michael B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2693385/michael-b) comment

Comment: I would suggest using `self.cleaned_data.get('email')` and `self.cleaned_data.get('email2')` instead. That's the problem. The `email` key is missing, thus the `KeyError` is being raised.